# authorized_keys challenge on OMVS under z/OS

Tags: mainframe, zos, omvs

I've done this before but yesterday and today I've had zero luck with getting the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file to work for a user on my z/OS system.

what I do is:

1. sftp to z/OS and issue `ls /+mode=text`
2. `cd .ssh`
3. `put id_rsa.pub authorized_keys`
4. quit the sftp session
5. try `ssh` to the system and get a prompt for password which I shouldn't.

I've tried

1. changing permissions to `644` and to `600` without success
2. tagging as IBM-1047 - no success

I'm sure there is something obvious but I'm not seeing it. This is effectively what I've done on other systems and userids.

Comment: Note that the `sftp` subcommand of `ls /+mode=text` only works if the server has the Dovetail Co:Z Toolkit installed which provides access to z/OS datasets.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure your .ssh directory only has permissions to read/write/execute for the owner:

```
chmod 700 ~/.ssh
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution was that the `~/.ssh` directory had permissions of 777.  Why I've no clue. Changed to 700 and all is good.